# Finding the column indices of submatrices in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Suppose I have the following matrix

```
 1     1     0     0     0
 1     1     0     0     0
 0     0     1     1     1
 0     0     1     1     1
 0     0     1     1     1
```

The result would be

```
{[1,2],[3,4,5]}
```

How would I implement this?

I have an ugly solution involving a loop that runs through the diagonal (except (1,1)) and checks whether the element directly left is 0. If not, that is the start of a new cluster.

Is there a prettier solution?

EDIT: current solution:

```
n = size(input, 2);
result = cell(1,n);
result{1} = 1;
counter = 1;
for i = 2:n
    if input(i,i-1) ~= 1
        counter = counter + 1;
    end
    result{counter} = [result{counter} i];
end
result =  result(~cellfun('isempty',result));
```

Comment: So, the output would be a cell array, right?

Comment: Your "ugly" solution might be a very good starting point, you may use `diag(M,-1)` to directly access all the left neighbours. Please put your best effort, either using a loop or diag, into the question. We will see if it can be improved. Please think about your expected output. There are no nested arrays in matlab, `[ , ]` concatenates. Thus `[[1,2],[3,4,5]]` is `[1,2,3,4,5]`. Maybe just return the start of each block: `[1,3]`

Comment: @Divakar Yes, correct. Updated the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for your reply. I have updated the question. I will have a look at diag now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `unique` with 'rows' argument on the matrix transposed

Comment: Very cool, thanks! `[~,B,~] = unique(H,'rows')` gives the desired result (more or less). `unique` does not appear to accept a 'col' argument (?), but it's fine either way since these type of matrices are symmetric.